# Сколько скобок нужно перевернуть, что бы сбалансировать строку из строк

Tags: python, строки

Как решить эту задачку? Нужно вернуть количество скобок, которые нужно перевернуть. Возвращать нужно минимальное количество.

Пример:
"(((())" - нужно перевернуть 1 "(" скобку.
")()(" - Нужно перевернуть 2 скобки.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Бьёте строку на две части. Потом в каждой из частей считаете скобки которые смотрят не в ту сторону.

Comment: Или имеется ввиду, что строки вида `(()())` или даже `(()((()()())))` тоже считаются сбалансированными?

Comment: Скобки в ")()(" сбалансированы...

Comment: @GrAnd Скобки, которые вы привели в пример считаются сбалансированными. Но когда разбиваешь на две части и считаешь, то строка в виде ")()(" выдает неправильный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

У меня получилось такое решение.
Считаю открывающиеся скобки как +1 и закрывающиеся как -1.
Постулата два:

1. Если при подсчёте баланса скобок получили -1, то скобку однозначно нужно переворачивать, ибо закрывающихся скобок на данный момент получается больше чем открывающихся.
2. Если до конца строки осталось столько символов сколько текущий баланс скобок, то оставшиеся скобки однозначно надо чтобы были закрывающимися.

```
def balance(s):
    n = count = 0
    result = ""
    s = list(s)
    while s:
        ch = s.pop(0)
        n += -1 if ch == ")" else +1
        if n < 0:  # закрывающаяся скобка раньше открывающейся - надо менять
            ch = "{"
            count += 1
            n += 2
        elif n > len(s): # открытых скобок набралось столько, что оставшиеся до конца надо все закрывать
            if ch == "(":
                ch = "}"
                count += 1
                n -= 2
        result += ch
    return (count, result)

tests = ["(((())", ")()(", "(()(())()())))", "))))", 
         "((((((", "(((()(", ")()()(((((", "())())",
         "(()())", "(()((()()())))"]
for test in tests:
    print(test, "==>", *balance(test))
```

Ну или если выкинуть все "рюшечки" из кода:

```
def balance(s):
    n = count = 0
    for i,ch in enumerate(s):
        if (not n and ch == ")") or (n >= len(s)-i and ch == "("):
            ch = "(" if ch == ")" else ")"
            count += 1
        n += -1 if ch == ")" else +1
    return count
```

Для наглядности ещё собирается конечная строка со скобками, где фигурными скобками обозначаются те скобки, что были перевёрнуты.
Результат:

```
(((()) ==> 1 (((}))
)()( ==> 2 {()}
(()(())()()))) ==> 1 (()(())()()){)
)))) ==> 2 {){)
(((((( ==> 3 (((}}}
(((()( ==> 2 (((})}
)()()((((( ==> 4 {()()((}}}
())()) ==> 1 (){())
(()()) ==> 0 (()())
(()((()()()))) ==> 0 (()((()()())))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за наглядный пример и решение. Я смог решить задачку вроде как таким же способом, но более оптимизированным.

Comment: @PeakyEye На все ваши четыре вопроса даны ответы, но вы почему-то ни одного не приняли (зеленая галочка, если ответ является подходящим решением)

Answer (score -1):

Поскольку это учебное задание могу только подсказать возможный ход мысли.

Можете идти по скобкам и считать баланс тех и других скобок. И смотрите, в каком случае их нужно переворачивать, а в каком нет. Например, открывающая скобка увеличивает баланс на 1, а закрывающая уменьшает на 1. Что будет, если баланс в какие-то моменты будет отрицательным? А если положительным? А что будет, если после прохода по всем скобкам баланс будет положительный? А если отрицательный? Вот надо ответить на все эти вопросы и понять, что со всем этим делать.

Comment: Чего-то вы переусложнили, как мне кажется. Я так понял, что в итоге должна быть простая строка из сначала только открывающихся скобок, а затем только из закрывающихся.

Comment: @GrAnd Не думаю что есть решение проще )

Comment: @CrazyElf Хорошо, спасибо. Подумаю получше.